# date minus 1 day during pipe chain

Tags: r, lubridate

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

I create a variable training_date:

```
training_date <- paste0(year(Sys.Date()), "-", format.Date(Sys.Date(), "%m"), "-01")
training_date
[1] "2020-04-01"
```

Elsewhere in my code I'd like to take this and subtract one day within a pipe chain:

```
month_end <- training_date %>% as_date() - 1
month_end %>% str
 Date[1:1], format: "2020-03-31"
```

I'd like month end to just be a string.
I could just do this:

```
month_end <- month_end %>% toString()
> month_end %>% str()
 chr "2020-03-31"
```

But I'd rather do it in a oner. Tried:

```
month_end <- training_date %>% as_date() - 1 %>% toString()
Error in unclass(as.Date(e1)) - e2 : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Then tried:

```
month_end <- training_date %>% (as_date() - 1) %>% toString()
Error in inherits(x, c("yearmon", "yearqtr")) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Then tried:

```
month_end <- training_date %>% (as_date(.) - 1) %>% toString()
Error in as_date(.) : object '.' not found
```

Then tried:

```
month_end <- training_date %>% (as_date(.) - 1) %>% toString(.)
Error in as_date(.) : object '.' not found
```

Then tried:

```
month_end <- training_date %>% as_date(.) - 1 %>% {toString()}
 Error in paste(x, collapse = ", ") : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Then tried:

```
month_end <- training_date %>% as_date() - 1 %>% {toString(.)}
Error in unclass(as.Date(e1)) - e2 : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

How can I take the variable training_date as defined at the top, turn it back into a date, subtract a day then turn it back into a string in one single chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-1` is the issue.

This works :

```
training_date %>% as_date() %>% toString()
#[1] "2020-04-01"
```

but this doesn't

```
training_date %>% as_date() - 1 %>% toString()
```

> Error in unclass(as.Date(e1)) - e2 : 
>     non-numeric argument to binary operator

So try :

```
training_date %>% {as_date(.) - 1} %>% toString()
#[1] "2020-03-31"
```